# Html div elements not moving on page resize

Tags: html, css

So I've got this grid created by div elements and what I need is that when I resize the browser the div elements should move down. I.e a 2 x 2 grid changes to a 1 x 4 grid. Currently nothing happens, the browser just moves over my content.

I really don't have a clue since the 'table' needs to have a fixed size and so do the elements but the elements have to move when the browser size is too small.

Html

```
<div class="table">
   <div class="element">
   </div>
   <div class="element">
   </div>
   <div class="element">
   </div>
   <div class="element">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table 
{
    font-size: 1.2em; 
    width: 800px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 565px; 
    background-color: #f0f0ee;
 }

.element 
{
    font-size: 1.2em; 
    font-family: monospace; 
    width: 48%; 
    border: 3px solid #FFF; 
    padding: 5px; 
    height: 50%; 
    float:left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfdffuvq/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elegant solution to get a 2x2 layout to collapse into a 1x4 layout when the window size gets too small. It works for any width and height of the inner elements. The way it works is by using an extra wrapper div to keep the 2x2 structure.

JSFiddle Example (shrink the size of the preview box to see the layout change to 1x4!): https://jsfiddle.net/bfdffuvq/3/

And here's the code inline as well:

```css
.inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: gray;
}

.innerwrap {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="innerwrap">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="innerwrap">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this? **Are you trying to make a responsive website? This doesn't happen by default.**

You need [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which provides you classes that can be used as responsive layout.

Check [this Youtube introduction and basic use of Bootstrap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXVoqJEwqoQ).

Also there's no way elements can resize when you used fixed sizes like "width: 800px;", "width: 80%;" (80% of parent element or screen if no parent) or "width: 80vw;" (80% of viewport aka browser window) might to the trick if you want to do this all yourself.

**If you want to achieve this without Bootstrap CSS:**

```
<div class="innerwrap top">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="innerwrap">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Add this to CSS (I also added widths):

```
.inner-wrap.top { 
    float: left; 
    width: 50%;
 }
.inner-wrap { 
    width: 50%;
 }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
   .inner-wrap.top { 
      float: none; 
      width: 100%;
   }
   .inner-wrap { 
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap is a major reason why people who write code don't really understand how CSS works, so I would not suggest that route.

Comment: It might affect something but you can't make a website without understanding CSS, not even with Bootstrap. **I belive that beginner doing everything himself makes too big CSS and other files which leads to long loading times, disappointment & giving up - not to mention very long developement cycles because you're not a pro.**

Comment: I need a responsize website in the sense that when the screen is too small the 2 right most divs drop down below the left divs. The size have to remain the same. And I know about bootstrap but I'm adjusting a site for a client who use joombla and I have no idea how to get it working there

Answer (score 0):

change `width: 800px` on the table to `max-width: 800px`

Comment: This doensn't completely help because the elements of the grid change size aswell because of the % width

Comment: You could fix the width of the inner elements. TBH, there are far more comprehensive answers here now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be responsive, never use `px` for that as `px` makes that fixed irrespective of size of the screen. It is good idea to use `%` instead of `px` as `%` makes it fit according to the size of the screen. You can set `min-width` property in CSS so that the next div moves to new line when the div has to be lower than that `min-width`.

Answer (score -1):

Your are explicitly defining the size of the outer container, so - nothing is just going to change that.

I would not define width or height, EVER... and just use the natural defaults of block-level elements, which would be width: 100%

Then, use `max-width: 800px;` or whatever you want.

You can use `@media queries to make rules based on screen size.

HTML

```
<ul class='grid'>
  <li>01</li>
  <li>01</li>
  <li>01</li>
  <li>01</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  margin: 0; padding: 0
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.grid li {
  /* width: 100%; by default */
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .grid li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

It would be hard to describe how CSS works in one post here, but this should get you pointed in the right direction. All those inline CSS rules lead me to believe there is a lot of copying and pasting going on. I suggest starting with a fresh mindset.

a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6u55y4q2/

Comment: But if I change the width to max-width all of the elements get smaller when resizing which it shouldn't. If you look at the jsfiddle that's the grid I want and they should stay that size until you can no longer see them all on one screen and thus the divs have to drop down

Comment: Then you just put a max width on the cells - and they will naturally float down because they are 'position: static;' by default.

Comment: Indeed a lot of copying and pasting since I'm continuing on someone elses work. I'm going to follow your advice and start fresh.